# Restoring JSF application state using memcached as session fail-over

Tags: session, jsf, serialization, memcached, restore

I set up two equal tomcat servers that host the same web application (Sun RI JSF 2 / Tomahawk). For load balancing and fail-over scenarios I use an nginx server as reverse proxy delegating the request to the one or the other server. Right now one tomcat is defines as backup solution, so that tomcat server 1 handles all the requests. When I kill the process of tomcat 1, nginx nicely delegates the following requests to tomcat server 2. In order to reuse the session data I configured both tomcat servers to use memcached as session store. JSF is configured to store its state on the server.

Concerning the log files, this setup looks quite nice and session data is read and stored using the memcached server. This for example facilitates using the web application without the need to login again even if tomcat 1 has been shut down.

Nevertheless it seems as if my (session scoped) backing beans are not stored or being used after restoring the session respectively. Form fields are left empty that are supposed to be filled with the data from the session bean.

Is it possible to do such things with the mentioned technologies at all?

Comment: To avoid the obvious, all whatever needs to go in the session already implements `Serializable`?

Comment: I think so. The only thing I forgot to mention is that I use CDI/OWB as well. To locate the error, I've written a small counter application, with the counter value being bound to a session scoped bean. The setup remains the same. I realised that the counter did not change the way it was supposed to when sending some requests with either the one or the other server in charge. After replacing OWB with Weld, the counter and thus restoring the state seems to work. The same applies if you don't use CDI at all. I will now replace OWB with Weld in the main app and let you know what the result is.

Comment: Are you using your own solution for storing sessions in memcached or memcached-session-manager (http://memcached-session-manager.googlecode.com)?

Comment: Hi Martin, I am using your memcached-session-manager

Answer (score 0):

With memcached-session-manager and OWB you should use tomcat < 7.0.22 as in this version the notification of ServletRequestListeners got changed (which is the mechanism used by OWB for failover support).

I'm currently working on a new version of msm that works with OWB and tomcat >= 7.0.22.